# Driver org.h2.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I started to work with springboot and come up with this error I cannot solve.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.h2.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb

My pom.xml dependencies

```
<properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.200</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

My application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
```

Comment: You are using an h2 JDBC driver, `org.h2.Driver` with a Postgres JDBC URL.

Answer (score 3):

you are incorrectly referring to h2 which is in memory database, change driver class name to

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```